# Get all elements in a LinkedList, exception

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I need to get all the elements in the linked list. I do this by calling the `get()` method in my buffer (**CharacterBuffer**).

But every time I try to get the elements I get a nullPointerException. I don't know how to solve this.

```
public class Reader extends Thread {
    private GUIMutex gui;
    private CharacterBuffer buffer;

    public Reader(GUIMutex gui, CharacterBuffer buffer) {
        this.gui = gui;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void run() {
        String data = "test";
        while (true) {

            try {
                System.out.println(buffer.get());
                gui.setReaderText(data + "\n");
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }
    }
}



public class CharacterBuffer {

    private char ch;
    private LinkedList buffer = new LinkedList();
    private boolean filled = true;

    public void put(char ch) {
        buffer.addLast(ch);
        buffer.removeFirst();
    }

    public Object get() throws InterruptedException {
        while (buffer.isEmpty()) {
            wait();
        }

        // return buffer.removeFirst();
        return buffer.getFirst();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you create the buffer and pass it to the reader? Where is the part where you actually call `put` and `get`? Also, please don't use raw types. Use `LinkedList<Character>`, and `Character get()`.

Comment: `String text = txtTrans.getText();
    buffer = new CharacterBuffer();
    writer = new Writer(gui, buffer, text);
    writer.start();
    reader = new Reader(gui, buffer);
    reader.start();`

Comment: get is called in the Reader class: `System.out.println(buffer.get());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing You can not use char in Linked List it only accept Wrapper type. And in your put method you are adding and removing character at the same time. No value will remain in your linkedlist.

Comment: Wow man this lol, was just a typo. Also RealSkeptic's answer helped me as well

Answer (score 1):

**LinkedList** is not threadsafe...
and threads get a copy of the memory when they exeute the run methode...

use instead something like a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`

look the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)